# Run jenkins-cli from Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, jenkins, jar, jenkins-cli

I need to start jenkins build job from `Intellij`, from terminal it works:

```
sudo java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:8080/ build job-x/master -s -v
```

Intellij allows to create jar build configuration, but it doesn't allow to run `jar` files with administrator rights. So is there way to create build configuration in `Intellij` which runs `jenkins-cli.jar`?

Initial problem: need to run and debug `jenkins pipeline` script.